# Particular site is not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser, http

I surf net in Ubuntu 12.04. All the sites are working, except one site `http://developer.android.com/`. I don't know why.

At the same time, the same url opens in Windows perfectly.

So the site is up and the problem isn't related to the proxy either.

I am totally feeling helpless. Why is this happening?

Firefox shows the error

> Server Not found

```
wget http://developer.android.com/

Resolving developer.android.com (developer.android.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget:unable to resolve host address 'developer.android.com'



ping developer.android.com

ping: unknown host developer.android.com
```

**cat /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      devsda

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosta
::1     ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
fe00::0    ip6-localnet
ff00::0    ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1    ip6-allnodes
ff02::2    ip6-allrouters
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
#  Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#  DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

**devsda@devsda:~$ host developer.android.com**

```
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
Host developer.android.com not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

**devsda@devsda:~$ host developer.android.com 8.8.8.8**

```
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

developer.android.com is an alias for www3.l.google.com.
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.33
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.37
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.35
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.39
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.32
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.46
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.38
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.40
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.41
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.36
www3.l.google.com has address 74.125.236.34
www3.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4007:800::1005
```

Comment: It seems like a browser issue rather than OS issue.  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can

Comment: Is the site opening in chrome browser inside Ubuntu?

Comment: @Ramesh Not working in chrome also.

Comment: A bad _hosts_ file maybe?

Comment: This appears to be a DNS resolution issue. Usually this is provided by your ISP. Is the Windows machine you are using on the same internet connection? Also please post the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @Graeme Yes, it works on Windows connected in the internet connection. Please see updated question.

Comment: Also, if you want a quick and dirty fix, you can add the line `173.194.34.142    developer.android.com` to your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Maybe your ISP's nameserver is not resolving some domains for some reason. Some have noted that [Comcast](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/14/03/11/1813226/crowdsourcing-confirms-websites-inaccessible-on-comcast) is silently blocking some domains from DNS resolution. Try running `host developer.android.com` to resolve with your default nameserver, then `host developer.android.com 8.8.8.8` to resolve with a Google DNS server to see if it's a problem with your default DNS server.

Comment: @Graeme If he can resolve the name using an alternate DNS server, then the solution to his problem is clear. If he can't, then the search goes on.

Comment: @Graeme - If an alternate DNS server solves his problem, he can [edit the resolvconf](http://askubuntu.com/a/157192/114581) config to hardcode the DNS server.

Comment: @Johnny, that would work, yes. But it would be a hack since it would bypass the local DNS. A better solution would be to configure it to use a different source (or perhaps just clear its cache).

Comment: @Johnny Please check update, and yes same site working on Windows. Secondly, when I added `173.194.34.142 developer.android.com` in  `/etc/hosts`, it works.

Comment: @Graeme `/etc/resolvconf.conf` is not present.

Comment: Could you install `dnsutils` and type `dig developer.android.com`. Also, when you say "windows work" you mean in the same system?

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the output of the `host` command shows, this is almost certainly a DNS server issue. Looking a little more into how this is generally configured in Ubuntu, it seems the best way to change this is simply through Network Manager. Network Manager offers per connection DNS settings, so the DNS settings can be fixed for the connection causing the problem and won't affect anything else. This [answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/90263) gives a good overview of how to do it, including screenshots.

To rehash:

1. Right click on the network icon on your desktop and select `Edit Connections`. Or simple run `nm-connection-editor` from the command line.
2. Select the tab for type of connection you have (wired or wireless), then the name of your connection and click `Edit...`
3. Go to the `IPV4 Settings` tab and enter `8.8.8.8` (or the IP of any other DNS server of your choosing) in the `DNS Servers` box.
4. Click save and you should be done!

Alternatively, just add the line `dns=8.8.8.8` to the relevant file (named after your connection) in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. The line should be added just after the `[ipv4]` line.

#### Caveats

If you have a wired connection, there may not already be a configuration for this under Network Manager. If this is the case, just click `Add`, choose the connection type and do everything else as above.

It may also be that there is a setting in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` for a system wide DNS server (this seems to be the place for it these days). If the file contains a line that begins `supersede domain-name-servers` and isn't commented out (it has a `#` at the beginning), this may be the case. If so, you can probably just remove this line, then disconnect/reconnect and your problem will be fixed. Note the file may be under `/etc/dhcp3` or `/etc/dhcp4` instead of `/etc/dhcp`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks (at least superficially) like a similar problem I had.

The content of `/etc/resolv.conf` is

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I am told that means your machine is running some kind of nameserver service locally.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` pointed to my router ISP address. I am not sure what nameserver it wound up using, but whatever it was, it was flaky.
So I used the package `resolvconf` in Debian (therefore also in Ubuntu) to add some stuff to `/etc/resolvconf`. Just adding text manually to `/etc/resolv.conf` does not work, because it gets overwritten. All I did was add the file
`/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`
with the contents

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

And now those lines get appended automatically to `/etc/resolv.conf`. So that fixed the issue. Hope that helps, and if this is off base, I can delete this answer.

Comment: AFAIK the `127.0.0.1` line is added by `Network Manager` via `resolvconf`. I'm not sure how changing the `resolvconf` configuration affects `Network Manager`. It may ignore `resolv.conf` altogether. Otherwise this is another valid way to change the DNS server globally.

Comment: @Graeme your comment assumes `Network Manager` is being used in the poster's case. Is this a given? I don't see it explicitly mentioned.

Comment: True, this is a best guess based on Ubuntu 12.04. I assume if the OP had something else installed, he would have mentioned it by now. AFAIK even KDE uses the network manager back-end.

Comment: Note also that `resolvconf` is not on Debian by default. `isc-dhcp` is a dependency for Network Manager, so my thinking was that it would be a more generic approach. Although Network Manager on Ubuntu used to use `dhcp3` (and possibly Network Manager can still be compiled to use this).

Comment: The poster could also be using `/etc/network/interfaces`. However, if Ubuntu enables Network Manager by default, I agree he is probably using that.